# Разделение строки по шаблону split + re Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть сплошной текст(Уголовный кодекс) Необходимо разбить его на статьи. Я разбиваю его так:

```
content = list("Статья "+ e for e in states.split("Статья "))
```

Но иногда статьи повторяются вот так:

'Статья 3. Разъяснение некоторы'

'Статья 3 дополнена пунктом'

Крайне необходимо в split добавить любая цифра и точка: типо этого -

```
content = list("Статья "+ e for e in states.split("Статья [\d+]."))
```

Пробую вот так:

```
content = list("Статья "+ e for e in re.split(r"Статья [\d+].", states))
```

Не то. Цифры пропадают

Вот строка для тренировок:

```
states='Статья 3. Разъяснение некоторы\nСтатья 3 дополнена пунктом\nСтатья 4. Разъяснение некоторы\nСтатья 4 дополнена пунктом'
```

Должен получиться список из двух строк

Вот так клево делит, но цифры пропадают:

```
content = list("Статья "+ e for e in re.split("Статья \d+\.", states))
```

Смастерил я полукостыли:

```
content = list(f"Статья {i}.{e}" for i, e in enumerate(re.split("Статья \d+\.", states)))
```

Comment: `content = ["Статья "+ e for e in states.split("Статья \d+\.")]`?

Comment: неа одна строка получилась

Comment: А ну, конечно, метод `spit` у строки не поддерживает регулярки. Нужно через `re.split` работать

Answer (score 2):

У меня получилось сделать это через предобработку:

- Разделение текста по строкам (через `\n`)
- Вытаскивание номера статьи из строки
- Группирование строк по номеру статьи в словаре, где ключом будет номер статьи, а значением список строк

Пример:

```
import re

states = 'Статья 3. Разъяснение некоторы\nСтатья 3 дополнена пунктом\nСтатья 4. Разъяснение некоторы\nСтатья 4 дополнена пунктом'

chapter_by_text = dict()
for line in states.splitlines():
    m = re.search(r'^Статья (\d+)', line)
    number = m.group(1)
    if number not in chapter_by_text:
        chapter_by_text[number] = []

    chapter_by_text[number].append(line)

print(chapter_by_text)
# {'3': ['Статья 3. Разъяснение некоторы', 'Статья 3 дополнена пунктом'], '4': ['Статья 4. Разъяснение некоторы', 'Статья 4 дополнена пунктом']}

items = [
    '\n'.join(v)
    for v in chapter_by_text.values()
]
print(items)
# ['Статья 3. Разъяснение некоторы\nСтатья 3 дополнена пунктом', 'Статья 4. Разъяснение некоторы\nСтатья 4 дополнена пунктом']
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: Вот результат трудов. https://t.me/ukrkbot

Comment: @ДмитрийБовак, , пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @ДмитрийБовак, посмотрел бота, интересно :) У меня тоже есть несколько ботов: https://github.com/search?q=user%3Agil9red+python-telegram-bot (все, кроме 
telegram__deep_dream_bot работают) ;) :D

Answer (score 1):

Ваш способ верен, только нужно использовать `re.split` (не `str.split`) и число нужно не захватывать, а лишь проверять на наличие с помощью блока предварительного просмотра вперёд:

```py
import re
content = list("Статья "+ e for e in re.split(r"Статья(?= \d+\.)", states))
```

Это регулярное выражение находит

- `Статья` - строку `Статья`...
- `(?= \d+\.)` - сразу после которой есть пробел, одна и более цифр, а затем символ точки.

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/RB1Qox/1/).